# Declaring array of pointers to char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

How come I can do this:

```
char a[] = {1, 2};
char b[] = {3, 4, 5};

const char *r[] = {
    a, b
};
```

But I can't do it this way:

```
const char *r[] = {
    {1,2}, {3,4,5}
};
```

Is there any shortcut for initializing an array of pointers to arrays of different length?

Comment: Because `{1, 2}` is not a pointer to `char`.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion on my last question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: yes. so he can write: `{"1, 2"}`

Answer (score 1):

this code doesn't work,

```
const char r[][] = {{1,2}, {3,4,5}};
```

fails with :

```
 x86-64 gcc 5.1!!error: declaration of 'r' as multidimensional array 
must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
```

fix it like so:

```
const char r[][3] = {{1,2}, {3,4,5}};
```

side note: it's a bad practice to use C-like arrays in c++ use std::array if you know your values at compile time.

---

EDIT:

you can do this ugly hack(it compiles, but I don't know how many rockets it will launch).

```
const char *r[] = { (const char[]){1,2}, (const char[]){1,2,3}};
```

Comment: Yes but how about when the 2nd level length is not the same? For example an array of pointers to char arrays (not string literals) whose values are known on compile time?

Comment: I think your first form is as short as you can get, there's no way to combine them.

Comment: The sub-arrays in your edit are C99 compound literals, they don't exist in C++. GCC offers them with an extension, but IIRC they're temporary instead of automatic, so that's immediade UB upon trying to access them...

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution to achieve the syntax you're looking for: these pointers have to point at *some* arrays, and these arrays must have an adequate lifetime.

You probably want them to be automatic, which implies declaring them as local variables the way you did.

You *could* achieve sort of what you want with dynamic allocation, i.e:

```
const char *r[] = {
    new char[]{1,2}, new char[]{3,4,5}
};
```

... in which case the arrays will have sufficient lifetime, but then you have the burden of `delete[]`ing them at the right time. Not really a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first form works because, when used like this, the name of each array is converted to a pointer (to its first element).    Since the result of the conversion is a `char *` it can be stored in an array of `char *`.

The second form doesn't work since `{1,2}` and `{3,4,5}` are (initialisers for) arrays, and arrays are not pointers.   An unnamed array (which these are) cannot be implicitly be converted to a pointer.

The first form IS the only shortcut to initialise an array of pointers, so each pointer points to the first element of an array.

You would be normally better off using standard containers (e.g. a `std::vector<std::string>`) and avoid the complexity of pointers (and conversions of array names to pointers) entirely.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write:

```
const char *r[] = { {1,2}, {3,4,5} };
```

because you cannot write:

```
r[0] = 1, 2, 3; // but you can r[0] = "1, 2, 3";
```

to initialize your array of pointers to char you can:

```
const char *r[] = {
    {"1,2"}, {"3,4,5"}};
```

so r is a an array of pointers to char.

Comment: The equivalent would be more something like `r[0] = "\x01\x02\x03"`.